# Writing express JS API with node.JS app error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, express

I'm trying to create a REST API in Express.js but I have some issues, **I hope that somebody can help me** )

my Express.js code:

```
  router.get( '/apps/download/:downloadId', function ( req, res, next ) {
    const opts = Object.assign( {downloadId: req.params.downloadId}, req.query );
      gplay.download( opts )
      .then( res.json(res) )
      .catch( next );
  });
```

My Node.js app jQuery code is:

```
const data = $( '.row' ).eq( 6 ).find( 'table tr' ).map( function() {
    const a = $( this ).find( 'td:first-child a' );
    const td = $( this ).find( 'td:last-child' );

    return {
        version: a.text(),
        href: a.attr( 'href' ),
        date: td.text()
    }
}).get();

console.log( data )

const sdata = $( '.row' ).eq( 7 ).find( 'table tr' ).map( function() {
    const a = $( this ).find( 'td:first-child a' );
    const td = $( this ).find( 'td:last-child' );

    return {
        version: a.text(),
        href: a.attr( 'href' ),
        date: td.text()
    }
}).get();

console.log( sdata )
```

So when I open `'/apps/download/:downloadId'` in the browser it gives me only console.log:

```
[
]

[
    {
         version: '1.0.2',
         href: '/download-app/com.playgendary.kickthebuddy/5_com.playgendary.kickthebuddy_2018-06-09.apk/',
         date: 'June 9, 2018'
    },

    {
         version: '1.0.1',
         href: '/download-app/com.playgendary.kickthebuddy/4_com.playgendary.kickthebuddy_2018-05-28.apk/',
         date: 'May 28, 2018'
    },

    {
         version: 'Varies with device',
         href: '/download-app/com.playgendary.kickthebuddy/5_com.playgendary.kickthebuddy_2018-05-22.apk/',
         date: 'May 22, 2018'
    }
]
```

However, in the tab browser I get this error: `"message": "Converting circular structure to JSON"`, but if I change `.then(res.json(res))` to `.then(res.json.bind(res))`, it gives me nothing, just a clear page.

*So I need to get all of this data in REST API on the page in JSON, so what should I do?*

Comment: `res.json(res)` Is this intended? You are sending `response` object as response body.

Comment: You are calling `res.json` with the `res` passed into the cb, rather than the result of the promise.

`.then(res.json(res))` should be `.then(promiseResult => res.json(promiseResult)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `res.json` with the `res` passed into the callback, rather than the result of the promise.

```
router.get('/apps/download/:downloadId', function (req, res, next) {
    const opts = Object.assign({downloadId: req.params.downloadId}, req.query);
      gplay.download(opts)
      .then(downloadResult => res.json(downloadResult))
      .catch(next);
  });
```

or

```
router.get('/apps/download/:downloadId', function (req, res, next) {
    const opts = Object.assign({downloadId: req.params.downloadId}, req.query);
      gplay.download(opts)
      .then(res.json)
      .catch(next);
  });
```

Comment: `.then(res.json)` gives me clean page.
`.then(downloadResult => res.json(downloadResult))` gives `{"message":"Cannot read property 'app' of undefined"}`

Comment: console.log still gives me result

Comment: thanks for your answer, it help me, i'm finally found reason of this problem !